# Adding points to persp-methods plots

Tags: r, plot, 3d

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wTVC.gif) I am working with R on Copula. I have plotted the copula, but I want to add my points to it like the image you see here. How I can do that?  My data include the x and y, I turned them to u and v. I need my point get added to the plot. But it did not show anything. When I add the points I receive this error "Error in cbind(x, y, z, 1) %*% pmat : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments"

```
library(copula)
library(lmomco)
library(VineCopula)

data <- read.csv('D:/test2.csv',header=F)

x <- data[,1]
y <- data[,2]

u <- pobs(x)
v <- pobs (y)

m <- cbind(u,v)
scopula <- r270GumbelCopula(-3)
fit1 <- fitCopula(scopula,m,method='mpl')
res <- persp(scopula, pCopula, zlim = c(0,1))
points(trans3d(m[,1], m[,2], pcop1, pmat = res), col = 2, pch = 16)
```

[example of Map I want to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RYZP.gif)

[What I can create so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6K2zH.png)

Comment: I don't follow really what the question is. You add points using `points` and `trans3d` as you've got in the above code.

Comment: `m <- cbind(u,v)
Error in cbind(u, v) : object 'u' not found`